# Cannot use react-pluralize library with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-pluralize'. '/node_modules/react-pluralize/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-pluralize` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-pluralize';`
```

Getting this error when importing react-pluralize in tsx file.

```
import Pluralize from 'react-pluralize';
```

There is no @types/react-pluralize library available on npm. How can I use react-pluralize in my react app (with TS) ?

Comment: It literally tells you in the error message "or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-pluralize';`"

Comment: I tried that before posting this question here, It didn't work

Comment: Is the declaration file included in tsconfig.json?

Comment: And isn't the question then "How to make tsc detect declaration file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no types, you have to declare it yourself.
As the compiler says you should create `declarations.d.ts` and add the following there:

`declare module 'react-pluralize';`

However, this will not add the types and only remove the errors. Though, you can include types yourself, something like this:

```
declare module 'react-pluralize' {
  function Component(props: { name: string }): any;
  export = Component;
}
```

Comment: I tried this with proper types of pluralize lib, but it didn't work

Comment: But did the initial error go away? If not include the that `.d.ts` file in `tsconfig.include`